# Memory issue on Loading images from Photo Library and sort them datewise

Tags: iphone, ios, photolibrary

I am fetching images from my photo library and according to assets's date property , I am arranging those images in a different folders . What I want to do is to fetch the image from photo library , store them according to date . e.g. if fetched image is from 23rd April, store them in "April" folder . I am using WSAssetPickerController for this. Please help me in solving memory issue as my app crashes due to the memory issue on device, this works fine in simulator.

```
- (void)storePhotos:(NSArray *)assets {

    int index = 0;

    for (ALAsset *asset in assets) {

        NSLog(@"Current asset :%@ ",asset);
        NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

        NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [format setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];

        NSString *photoDate = [format stringFromDate:[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate]];

        resourceDocPath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:photoDate];

        // Create directory & Check directory
        BOOL checkDir = [self createDocumentDirectory:resourceDocPath fileName:asset.defaultRepresentation.filename];

        if (!checkDir) {
            continue;
        }

        // Write image
        NSString *writablePhotoPath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:asset.defaultRepresentation.filename];
        [self writeImage:writablePhotoPath WithImage:asset.defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage];

        index++;
    }
}

- (void)writeImage:(NSString*)pstrPhotoPath WithImage:(CGImageRef)pImage {

     if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pstrPhotoPath]){

         UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:pImage];
         NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
         [imageData writeToFile:pstrPhotoPath atomically:YES];

     }
}

- (BOOL)createDocumentDirectory:(NSString*) pCurrentFolder fileName:(NSString*) pStrFileName  {

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pCurrentFolder]){

        if ([self checkPhotoIsExistInDocument:pStrFileName]) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        NSError* error;
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:pCurrentFolder withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]) {
            // success
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"[%@] ERROR: attempting to write create MyFolder directory", [self class]);
            NSAssert( FALSE, @"Failed to create directory maybe out of disk space?");
            return TRUE;
        }
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}

- (BOOL)checkPhotoIsExistInDocument:(NSString*) pStrImageName {

    NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [manager enumeratorAtPath:bundleRoot];

    NSString *filename;

    while ((filename = [direnum nextObject] )) {
//        NSLog(@"%@", filename);
        if ([filename hasSuffix:pStrImageName]) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: are you using ARC code??

Comment: Yes, I am using ARC in my code

Comment: make it nil the objects you have allocated as well you can make use of leaks tool to manage your memory

Comment: @Leena is it worth to load all the images from photo library to the application.

Comment: i too have loaded all the images but i have loaded thumbnails of the images in a tableview

Comment: @Leena I too want to sort the images in grid view according to its date

Comment: i too have sorted images in gridview as per the date

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ARC in your project? Because you have not released any objects which you are allocating and initializing.

```
resourceDocPath
format
image
bundleRoot
```

Should be released as soon as their use is over. Also if you can provide the logs of your application crash that would be very useful.